# How to kill all servers running in gulp using one bash command

Tags: django, bash, gulp, kill-process, gulp-watch

I have created a `gulpfile.js` to start my servers, and its content can be seen below.

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    if(!fs.statSync('/etc/aptly.conf').isFile()){
    process.exit();
    return;
    }

    console.info('Starting static file server SimpleHTTPServer on 0.0.0.0:8080');
    aptly_static = spawn('python', ['-m', 'SimpleHTTPServer', '8080'], {'cwd': '/opt/aptly/public', 'stdio': 'inherit'});

    console.info('Starting Django runserver on 0.0.0.0:8000');
    django = spawn('python', ['manage.py', 'runserver', '0.0.0.0:8000'], {'stdio': 'inherit'});

    console.info('Starting Aptly api serve on 0.0.0.0:4416');
    aptly_api = run('aptly api serve -listen="0.0.0.0:4416"').exec().pipe(gulp.dest('/tmp/aptlylog'));

    return watchLess('src/**/*.less')
    .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(reLess)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/dist'));
```

The problem is if less preprocessor crashes for any reason, the gulpfile.js daemon exits poorly. The child processes `python manage.py runserver` `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` `aptly api serve` will still be running.

I have had to painstakingly terminate these by using a `ps -aux | grep runserver` and similar to find the PID to delete via `sudo kill -9 $PID`.

Is there a way to directly kill all the processes if my gulpfile.js crashes unexpectedly?

Comment: You may find `pkill -f runserver` makes the last part smoother at least.

Comment: Yes I know but again, I have to fire three pkill commands. I am looking to combine these commands into one.

Comment: I am planning to just write a bash script to kill all servers. Do you think its a good idea? or there are some better methods out there

Comment: If the names of the processes to be killed are known in advance, call 'em *p1*, *p2*, *p3*, then why not:  **for f in p1 p2 p3 ; do pkill $f ; done**, perhaps with a few other *pkill* options as needed.

Comment: If your process is run via a dedicated user, `pkill -u YourUser`
What is the state of these processes ? zombie  or not ? 
Is the parent PID stay visible ? in this case `pkill -P -f runserver`

Comment: killall -SIGPROF python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a recurive function to send kill signal to all child processes.
Create the following ./killChilds.sh file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function KillChilds {
    local pid="${1}" # Parent pid to kill childs
    local self="${2:-false}" # Should parent be killed too ?

    if children="$(pgrep -P "$pid")"; then
        for child in $children; do
            KillChilds "$child" true
        done
    fi

    # Try to kill nicely, if not, wait 15 seconds to let Trap actions happen before killing
    if ( [ "$self" == true ] && kill -0 $pid > /dev/null 2>&1); then
        kill -s TERM "$pid"
        if [ $? != 0 ]; then
            sleep 15
            kill -9 "$pid"
            if [ $? != 0 ]; then
                return 1
            fi
        else
            return 0
        fi
    else
        return 0
    fi
```

}

Source the file in your bash with

```
source ./killChilds.sh
```

You can that use it to kill the whole process tree in console with

```
killChilds $pid
```

Where $pid is the main process.
You might wanna include the file to ~/.bashrc so you don't have to source it every time.